# Updating a column in a table when multiple conditions match to another table. Getting "At most one record can be returned by this subquery"

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am not that experienced with SQL and I am not exactly sure how to troubleshoot this. However, when I use the same conditions in Python with the same tables (outputted as XLSX) I get multiple results. I am using MS Access also why I cannot use CONCAT for the date.

Code:

```
UPDATE tbl_a a
SET a.[Type] = "UPDATED TEXT"
WHERE (a.[Year/Month] = (SELECT iif(b.[Month] > 9, b.[Year] & "/" & b. 
[Month], b.[Year] & "/0" & b.[Month]) FROM [tbl_b] b)) AND (a.[Key_1] = 
(SELECT b.[key_1] FROM [tbl_b] b)) AND (a.[Key_2] = (SELECT b.[key_2] FROM 
[tbl_b] b)) AND (a.[Key_3] = (SELECT b.[key_3] FROM [tbl_b] b)) AND (a. 
[Key_4] = (SELECT b.[key_4] FROM [tbl_b] b)) AND (a.[Type] = "OLD TEXT");
```

Basically from what I understand is I am trying to match all the conditions in one table with another table and replace the TYPE with some "UPDATED TEXT". Had to use an IF statement for the Year because the tables have different formatting for the dates.

Comment: If `tbl_b` has more than one record, all of (far as I can see ) your subqueries return more than one row in scalar context. Start with adding a `WHERE` clause to them as they completely miss one each.

Comment: tbl_b has many records, I want them to return multiple rows so that I can check to see if it matches any of them. "they completely miss one each" sorry can you expand on this? If I am understanding this correctly I should remove a.[Year/Month] = and put a WHERE clause at the end of each SELECT and add b.[Year]&"/"b.[Month] = a.[Year/Month] ?

Comment: I cannot see a `WHERE` clause in any of your subqueries. Thus they all completely miss one as far as I can see. And that means they return more than one row in a context where only one (or no) row is allowed.

Comment: Okay I understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The `=` operator doesn't work when one side of the comparison is a set of records. You *could* replace `=` with `IN`, but what you really want to do is `JOIN` your two tables together. Take all the conditions in your `WHERE` clause that reference some column from tbl_a being the same value of some other column in tbl_b, and move those into the `JOIN` condition.

You should end up with something like this:

```
UPDATE tbl_a a
INNER JOIN tbl_b b ON a.[Key_1] = b.[key_1] 
                        AND a.[Key_2] = b.[key_2] 
                        AND a.[Key_3] = b.[key_3] 
                        AND a.[Key_4] = b.[key_4]
                        AND a.[Year/Month] = iif(b.[Month] > 9, b.[Year] & "/" & b.[Month], b.[Year] & "/0" & b.[Month])
SET a.[Type] = "UPDATED TEXT"
WHERE a.[Type] = "OLD TEXT"
```

The `INNER JOIN` matches records from tbl_a with records in tbl_b where the column values match.

EDIT: Fixed Access SQL syntax per Parfait's comment.

Comment: You can also use exists

Comment: This seems to be good just running into problems with mismatched datatypes. Thank you!